# Phase factor in the equal time commutation relation in Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

Two related questions regarding the equal-time commutation relation in the Klein-Gordon field (I suspect they have the same/very related answers):

In the following notes http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/FabianEssler/C6web2012/theory/canonical.pdf, they have:
[image]

My question is going from the second to the third line -- shouldn't we have an overall factor of $e^{- i (\omega_p - \omega_q)t}$ in front of the integral because the $p, q$ in the second line are four-vectors and not three-vectors?

Alternately here [http://cftp.ist.utl.pt/~gernot.eichmann/2015-qft/qft-2.pdf](http://cftp.ist.utl.pt/%7Egernot.eichmann/2015-qft/qft-2.pdf), they have:

[image]

and my question is why we don't have $e^{- i (E_p - E_q)t} [a_p, a_{p'}^\dagger] = [a_p(t), a_{p'}^\dagger(t)]$ instead of the $[a_p, a_{p'}^\dagger] = [a_p(t), a_{p'}^\dagger(t)]$ shown in the equations above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $[a_p,a^\dagger_{p}]\propto \delta^3(p-p')$ so $p$ has to equal $p'$ and hence $E_p=E_{p'}$.